# Separating the list into particular types

Tags: python

How to separate lists into particular types so that a dictionary is created at the end, e.g.:

```
input = [False, 333, 234.234, 'ert5rr']

output = {
    'bool': [False],
    'str': ['ert5rr']
    'float': [234.234],
    'int': [333],
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def separate_types(input_list):
    return {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(input_list, key=type), key=lambda x: type(x).__name__)}
```

It's pretty fast and I think that a nice pythonic way of doing it. The only thing is that Python's `groupby` function works on consecutive elements, it only works correctly here because we first sort the input list by type. If the input list isn't sorted by type, the output might not be correct. For example, if the input list was `[1, 'a', 2, 'b']`, the output would be `{'int': [1], 'str': ['a'], 'int': [2], 'str': ['b']}` instead of `{'int': [1, 2], 'str': ['a', 'b']}`

test:

```
input_list = [False, 333, 234.234, 'ert5rr']
output_dict = separate_types(input_list)
print(output_dict)
```

output:

```
{'bool': [False], 'int': [333], 'float': [234.234], 'str': ['ert5rr']}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should give the results you expect

```
def dict_types(liste):
empty_dict={}
for i in liste:
    if str(type(i)) in empty_dict.keys():
        empty_dict[type(i).__name__].append(i)
    else:
        empty_dict[type(i).__name__]=[i]
return empty_dict
```

print(dict_types([1,2,3,4,5,'test',1.0,"<--float"]))

it's clearly not the best way of doing it , but it works

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use the following function:

```py
input = [False, 333, 234.234, 'ert5rr']

def input_list_to_dict_by_type(input_list: list) -> dict:
    output = {}
    for item in input_list:
        # Get the name of the current item type
        item_type = type(item).__name__
        # If it is in our output dictionary, we will append to list
        if item_type in output:
            output[item_type].append(item)
        # Add new key to dict. The target item will also be appended 
        # as first entry in the list
        else:
            output[item_type] = [item]
    return output

print(input_list_to_dict_by_type(input))
```

you should get the following output:

```
{'bool': [False], 'int': [333], 'float': [234.234], 'str': ['ert5rr']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_dic(list_input, dic):
    for d in list_input:
        o = str(type(d).__name__)
        dic[o] = str(d)
    return dic


list_input = [False, 333, 234.234, 'ert5rr']
dic = {}

print(create_dic(list_input, dic))
```

The result will be:
{'bool': False, 'int': 333, 'float': 234.234, 'str': 'ert5rr'}

Comment: This will only work if `input` contains only one object of each type; plus, don't call your dictionary `dict`, thus overwriting a Python built-in.

Comment: @Swifty You are right about changing dict, I edited my answer. However, regarding the dictionary this is how it works, it doesn't repeat keys. Otherwise, if someone needs a solution for a list that contains objects with repeated types, then your answer is perfect for them.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the heck of it, an ugly solution:

```
input = [False, 333, 234.234, 'ert5rr', 'foo']
output = {}

for item in input:
    output[type(item).__name__] = output.setdefault(type(item).__name__, []) + [item]

print(output)

# {'bool': [False], 'int': [333], 'float': [234.234], 'str': ['ert5rr', 'foo']}
```